# VS2019 Publish: Produce single file will change the Basedir

Tags: c#, directory, visual-studio-2019, publish

I am trying to use the publish functionality of Visual Studio 2019. When I try to use the option "Produce single file", the base directory is not anymore the folder in which the executable lies, but an path in temp local Appdata.
If I dont use that option it is correct.

[image: Publish Settings]

I tried both:

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

and

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

. Both with the same result. It is the same wether I start it via the Executable directly or as a Windows Service.
How can I acces the path of the directory in which the executable lies during runtime, with the usage of the single file option?

Comment: Did you save project use File : SaveAll?  The only time you get a temp\localAppdata is when you start a new project and don't save the project to a file location.  The default folder of a project is in the temp folder.  Usually a project is save in the users Document folder.

Comment: Yes I saved the Project. As I said it usually works (debugging as well), just not if I use the produce single file option.

Comment: I'm not sure why the base directory would change with just checking the Produce Single File.  I suspect something else changed.  Usually errors like this occur with differences in the debug folder and release folder.  Depending on version of VS sometimes debug gets updated and not release.  So the debug version works but not the release version.  Doing a clean build a making sure both the debug and release version are built usually solve these type issues.

Comment: I really wouldn't have expected this behavior either, however this is really all I changed. I have the option disabled, it works, I enable it, it does not work. I change it back, it works again. Nothing else changed (like the configuration Debug/Release). Doesnt matter if I delete the publish and normal build Folder.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file), a temporary directory will indeed be generated in .NET Core 3.0. You can try to submit a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=61).